# Eliminar salto en gráfico

Tags: r

Convierto en una serie temporal los datos de AirPassengers y hago una predicción.

```
datos = ts(AirPassengers, frequency = 12, start = c(1949, 1))

datos.hw <- HoltWinters(datos, seasonal="multiplicative")

library(forecast)

prediccion <- forecast(datos.hw, h=24, prediction.interval = TRUE, level=95)  

plot(prediccion)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo hago para eliminar el salto entre los datos y la predicción y que parezca una sola linea?
En este ejemplo el salto no parece tan grande, pero otras veces si que se nota bastante.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La idea es que no haya continuidad, ya que son dos gráficas distintas. Sin embargo si quieres unirlas, nada te impide "dibujar" una línea entre la última observación y la primer predicción:

```
union <- data.frame(x = c(tsp(prediccion$x)[2],
                          tsp(prediccion$mean)[1]),
                    y = c(tail(prediccion$x,1),
                          head(prediccion$mean,1))
)

plot(prediccion)
lines(union)
```